# Fighting ticket driven development in agile/scrum?

Tags: agile, scrum

Our team has the problem (and benefit) of having a very stubborn project manager.  He insists that all discussion of tickets happen during grooming sessions.  He is the one who selects which tickets from the backlog will be groomed based on business needs, developers do not have input on what gets groomed.  However, he also will not share information ahead of time about what tickets will get discussed so it's always a surprise what we'll be discussing.  We don't do user story tickets, we do 'task' style tickets that are typically broken down into UI and API tasks inside of a single epic.

This is complicated by the fact that we're a single team supporting a dozen different applications.

I've fought, and lost, the battle to have him send out which tickets he wants to cover ahead of time so the developers have time to think about the tickets and architectural implications in advance.

This is creating a problem of ticket-driven development.  We end up committing to tickets with little architectural thought and a codebase that is sprawling and where implementation details shift constantly.

How and what would you change in such a situation?

Answer (score 3):

Refuse to commit prematurely.

You should never commit before you are ready. You should feel confident that you can complete the ticket on time. If you don't then don't commit to it. If this leaves you with no tickets so be it. Don't commit to more than you know you can do.

You seem to be in a power struggle. The best response is to be stubbornly reasonable. The team could agree to hold off committing to tickets until they've had time study them. But understand, you don't decide what you work on. Under Scrum you decide what you're willing to put in the sprint time box. Even if it's only evaluation.

The retrospective is the meeting where these kinds of changes get formally introduced but talk with your team mates ahead of time about this idea. It's easier to get a problem fixed if you aren't the only one bringing it up.

Barring that, if you’re doing story points the planning poker cards allow for this situation. Play the ? card to get a chance to ask questions and the  ∞ card to force elevating the story to an epic until it starts with an evaluation story.

If that seems far to long to do an evaluation then it may be that your sprints are to long. I prefer week long sprints myself but you don’t always get what you want.

None of this works well if you’re the only one with an issue though so talk to your teammates